# reading char from console

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I have a problem really SIMPLE =.=. I want to scan character from console and here is my code:

```
char odp;
 printf("Czy uwazasz ze z Twoimi oczami jest coś nie w porzadku?\n");
    scanf("%c",&odp);
    printf("ZNAK ZCZYRTANY: %c\n",odp);

    while(odp != 't' || odp != 'n'){
        printf("zle dane wprowadz jeszcze raz\n");
        scanf("%c",&odp);
    }

    if(odp == 'n') /* prawa galaz */ //JAKO "NIE" POZIOM 1
    {
        printf("Kontrola u okulisty jest potrzebna czesciej niz myslisz\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that when I print this character it shows me "t" or "n" but it does not want me get throught. What is wrong here?

Comment: change `while(odp != 't' || odp != 'n'){` to `while(odp != 't' && odp != 'n'){`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. My fault. Thanks again.

Comment: Hope you won't mind a little tip: do not use `system("pause")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You had two problems

- one was with the if condition. it should be 
  odp != 't' && odp != 'n'
- the scanf was leaving a '\n' on the stdin. This was causing your second scanf() to fail. So 
  you can flush this '\n' using another dummy character.

try this

```
char odp;
char newline;
printf("Czy uwazasz ze z Twoimi oczami jest coś nie w porzadku?\n");
scanf("%c%c",&odp,&newline);
printf("ZNAK ZCZYRTANY: %c\n",odp);

while(odp != 't' && odp != 'n'){
    printf("zle dane wprowadz jeszcze raz\n");
    scanf("%c%c",&odp,&newline);
}

if(odp == 'n') /* prawa galaz */ //JAKO "NIE" POZIOM 1
{
    printf("Kontrola u okulisty jest potrzebna czesciej niz myslisz\n");
    system("sleep 10");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for the answer. Nice trick with \n character;]

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helped resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look again at this. Do you know why it shows me twice or more times that printf in while loop even if I enter the right answer (the right key)?

```
printf("Czy uwazasz ze z Twoimi oczami jest coś nie w porzadku?\n");
    scanf("%c",&odp);

while(odp != 'T' && odp != 'N'){
    printf("zle dane wprowadz jeszcze raz");
    scanf("%c",&odp);
}

if(odp == 'N') /* prawa galaz */ //JAKO "NIE" POZIOM 1
{
    printf("Kontrola u okulisty jest potrzebna czesciej niz myslisz\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
else if(odp == 'T') //LEWA GALAZ POZIOM 1
{
    printf("Czy bola Cie oczy?\n");
    scanf("%c",&odp);

    while(odp != 'T' && odp != 'N'){
        printf("zle dane wprowadz jeszcze raz");
        scanf("%c",&odp);
    }

    if(odp == 'T')
    {

        printf("Kontrolujesz tonus - cisnienie galkowe?\n");
        scanf("%c",&odp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have explained this in my answer above. The issue is with the scanf(). Please change all scanf() call to scanf("%c%c",&odp,&newline); as explained above.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that and thank you again for help